# GWT tab panel creation in uibinbder cause issue

Tags: gwt

I am creating a tabPanel in GWT Uibinder

```
          <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barUnit='PX'
        barHeight='40' width="100%" height="100%">
        <g:tab>
            <g:header size='7' >
            My tab Name 
            </g:header>
            <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="tabConfiguration" >
                <div>
                </div>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
```

Now when i try to put my internationalized text it doesnt work :

```
            <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barUnit='PX'
        barHeight='40' width="100%" height="100%">
        <g:tab text = "{i18n.CONFIGURATION}">
            <g:header size='7' >
            My tab Name 
            </g:header>
            <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="tabConfiguration" >
                <div>
                </div>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
```

It simply gives me an empty tab , with no name

any work around for this .

Please not : in this file if i apply this same I8n text to any other widget its works perfectly.

Comment: I don't think the (inner class) `Tab` in `TabLayoutPanel` has a `text` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

`<g:tab` is not a widget, but a uibinder child element of `TabLayoutPanel`. Therefor you can't use it as a widget. To make it work with plain text you need to set the text in the header element with `<ui:text ..>` on the same place as in your first example:

```
<g:header size='7' >
  <ui:text from="{i18n.CONFIGURATION}" />
</g:header>
```